# stitching of two images and blending them together in java

Tags: java

I have a case, where , i need to attach two images and blend them together. I have been trying various methods,but i not able to zero in to one final method. I'm able to join the images together, but there is a narrow gap coming in between the two images, and the color of the output image is reddish color.

Comment: *"output image is reddish color"* is due to `ImageIO`'s inability to deal with transparent JPGs.  Either use PNG format or don't use `BufferedImage.TYPE_ARGB`  The narrow gap could be any number of reasons, misalignment in the images, miscalculation in their sizes and/or borders within the images themselves

Comment: oh... thanks... i will look at it and come back.

Comment: @MadProgrammer JPG does not support transparency at all. @AVGSankeerth: So you have two `java.awt.Image` instances (that you read with `ImageIO`), and both have a size of, for example, 300x200 pixels, and now you want to combine them into *one* image with 600x200 pixels. Is this correct?

Comment: @Marco13 Actually, apparently it can carry the alpha data, don't know if any one shows, this is why some times when reading JPGs in, they come in reddish, as Java can't decode them properly, it's really a rather common problem...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Any examples for this? I did not find such questions with a websearch or so, and can't remember having encountered such a problem (except when people manually messed around with ColorSpace and RGB values etc)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes!!! That is absolutely what im looking for...